# IIS backup physical path

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, html

I am new to IIS and currently doing a lab on company.

So I have 2 volumes, each stored the same html files that use to display the IIS web.

Is there a way to set my physical path to point up to both of their directory? Just in case if one volume down, the other still up and keep the web alive?

If no then is there anyway for me to achieve this?

Comment: High availability of IIS comes from web farms (load balancing), not what you imagined above.

Comment: Can you please show me or be more specific? Sorry because i am new to this, thanks.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/network-load-balancing